# Vue Router Push method within Nuxt causing a page reload

Tags: vue-router, nuxt.js

Working on a Nuxt project and trying to programmatically change route.

In a method I am using this:

```
$nuxt.$router.push({
    path: `vehicles-for-sale`
})
```

This looks like it initially works, but it then causes a page refresh to '/vehicles-for-sale?.

Is there anything different I need to do with Nuxt to get this working? I have a pages folder called 'vehicles-for-sale' and an index.vue file within that.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this:

```
this.$router.push('vehicles-for-sale')
```